# Q-learning with 2D actions and 2D states

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, artificial-intelligence, reinforcement-learning

My problem is as follows:

The agent should at each state, adjust the water flow and a fan speed for a power plant boiler to receive a feedback of a double state: current temperature, amount of emissions.

If my agent has a tuple of actions and a tuple of states, does that mean i should split my q-learning problem into 2 where 1 agent would have a Q and R matrix for the water/temperature environment and the other agent for the fan speed/amount of emissions environment? Or is there a way to represent an R and Q matrix for the agent described originally?

Comment: It's all about rewards. This means you have to build one reward consisting of both terms (temperature and emission). As these are probably conflicting, you need to define some model (as in multi-objective optimization). You have to control which of these is how important to you / which solution of temp/em is preferred to some other.  Having a multidimensional state is not uncommon and just means that your Q-function has multiple inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is normal for states and actions to be multidimensional. What you do is have your agent learn the values of all combinations of water flow and fan speed for all combinations of current temperature and amount of emission. If this makes the table unwieldy, then you will need to approximate it, and this is a whole field in itself.

Comment: Then in my problem, i would have a 40 by 40 q-matrix. How can i know it's unwieldy? Does approximating Q with a simple NN makes things more efficient?

Comment: @Leb_Broth, try and see. If I had to use an approximation, I would try coarse coding and linear function approximation before resorting to neural nets.